# how to print out a username and user age based on session login

Tags: php

i am fairly new to php. I am trying to print out the username and age based on the user session login, and cant seem to figure it out. 
I have two separate table, one for login and another that contains the users info.

> user table   id-> 1 | logon -> shawn@aol.com | passwrd -> somthing
>      usersinfo    id-> 1 |  logon ->shawn@aol.com | username -> mathewkng1 | age -> 23

i can print out the session login using `$_SESSION['logon']`, this will give shawn@aol.com
 what i want to do is instead of printing out shawn@aol.com i want to print out mathewkng1, age 23.

i tried,

```
SELECT users.*, usersinfo.* FROM users, userinfo WHERE users.logon = userinfo.logon

 $logon = session_start();

if($_SESSION['logon']){
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($user )){
$username = $rows['username '];
$age= $rows['age'];

}
echo " .$username." <br> ".$age." ";
}
```

i get the following error $username and $age not defined.

Comment: That indicates that while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($user) never fires which indicates that your SQL query did not return any rows. Please supply more information. Like the real source code you use for executing your SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First advice is not to relay on the logon as a key for the second table. Rather use a field id_user instead of logon an id in the userinfo table.

then you can change also the select to

```
Select * from users join userinfo on users.id = userinfo.id_users
```

then you have an typo in

```
$username = $rows['username '];
```

i don't see where you do $_SESSION['logon'] and what you add there but i guess that it is an ID of that users table, so you should add that to the select up there.

Comment: $username = $rows['username '];  the space at the end doesn't affect it, $_SESSION['logon'] is not login that the person log in with, this is what determines if the correct person is logon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $rows['username '];
```

There is a space within the string behind `username`. I guess that shouldn't be there. Also, I cannot see if these tables contain an age. If $username is not defined, it might be because there is no record returned. Assumingly there is an error in your query (could by a Duplicate Fieldname error because both returned tables will contain the same logon field), but there could also be an error in the way you execute the query.

Please try these suggestions and check for the result of mysql_query and mysql_fetch_* to see if an error occurred. If mysql_query returns false (check using the `===` operator), get the result of mysql_error() to see what the exact error is. 
Post that error and a little more code if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your table structure, you don't need the join.

This sould be sufficient:

`SELECT * from usersinfo where logon = 'shawn@aol.com'`

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['logon'])
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usersinfo WHERE logon=" . $_SESSION['logon']
    $res = mysql_query($user, $sqlConnection)

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $username = $row['username'];
        $age= $row['age'];
    }

    echo $username ." <br /> ".$age;
}
```

Comment: in that case, as others have noted, your mysql query is not returning any results.